# How to show the subset is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R} \setminus X$ is countable.　Let $f$ be a continuous function from $X$ to a Hausdorff space. Let

$$M_f=\left\{x\in X: |f^{-1}f(x)|>1\right\}$$

and

$$S_k=\left\{(x,y):\frac{1}{k}\le|x-y|, f(x)=f(y)\right\}$$ How to show $S_k$ is closed in $X\times X$? And if $M_f$ is uncountable, then so is $S_k$ for some $k \in \omega\setminus \{0\}$? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using $\,\omega\,$ to denote $\,\Bbb N=\,$ the natural numbers?

Comment: @DonAntonio: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $$E=\big\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times X:f(x)=f(y)\big\}\;,$$ and for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$D_k=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times X:|x-y|\ge\frac1k\right\}\;.$$

Use the fact that the range of $f$ is Hausdorff to show that $(X\times X)\setminus E$ is open and hence that $E$ is closed. Similarly, show that $(X\times X)\setminus D_k$ is open and hence that $D_k$ is closed. Then $S_k=E\cap D_k$ is also closed.

For each $x\in M_f$ there is a $\varphi(x)\in M_f$ such that $x\ne\varphi(x)$ and $f(x)=f\big(\varphi(x)\big)$. For each $x\in M_f$ let $$k(x)=\min\left\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:|x-\varphi(x)|\ge\frac1n\right\}\;;$$ then $\langle x,\varphi(x)\rangle\in E_{k(x)}$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $A_n=\{x\in M_f:k(x)=n\}$. If $M_f$ is uncountable, at least one of the sets $A_n$ is ... what?